# Не перегружается оператор '>>'

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, ввод

По какой причине может не перегружаться оператор '>>'

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Set& set)
    {
        if (set._capacity != 0)
            delete[] set._ptr;

        in >> set._capacity;
        in >> set._size;

        set._ptr = new T[set._capacity];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < set._size; i++)
            in >> set._ptr[i];

        return in;
    }
```

При передаче в качестве istream cin

```
    Set<int> voidSet();

    cin << voidSet;
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand 
operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable 
conversion) '
```

Comment: У вас параметрах функции написано просто `Set`, а пытаетесь объявить переменную типа `Set<int>`. В вашем случае Set - это шаблон или обычный класс?

Answer (score 0):

`Set<int> voidSet();` - это объявление функции `voidSet`, которая возвращает тип `Set<int>`.

Пишите `Set<int> voidSet{};` или `Set<int> voidSet;`